# What ebook reader synchronises between Windows and Android?

Tags: ebook-readers

What e-books software synchonizes between a Windows PC and an Android smartphone?

Currently I use FBreader for my phone and Microsoft Edge for PC. But it's not convenient, because I need to download the book to my phone and PC, and when I finish reading from my phone/PC, and switch to another device, I have to look for the place where I stopped by keywords.

Ideally, I would prefer something like Google Books. I would like to upload a book to cloud/share and I can read the book from the application on Android and from the web/app version for PC. The reader synchronizes all the notes and synchronizes the place where I finished reading.

Unfortunately, Google Books web version is does not work well. The book search doesn't work (it's critical for me) and the customization is very limited (which is not critical but uncomfortable), and it doesn't save customization when I quit a book.

Answer (score 1):

After long time of research I can say, that Bookmate is not bad. 
Props:
- sync between devices:
1) saving where I stopped read;
2) sync notes/highlights;
- can upload my books.

Cons:
- unavailable search in book;
- bad work with highlights (if the highlights are too many, some old will be not be displayed)

I notified a support about cons, they said that know about it and they work on it, but if to take into account that those cons have been around for a long time, I doubt that they will not fix in the near future. In spite of that, it's the best if we can find based on the current time, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: fbreader for me on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Microsoft declared EDGE will no longer be able to show EPUB files, so when they get a patch into your system to kill that ability, it's gone forever.

As Microsoft stated, other EPUB reader apps are available, including the Open Source [fbReader for Windows](https://fbreader.org/win32), as well as 12 others in the Microsoft Store.  fbReader offers bookmark and other sync across platforms as per https://books.fbreader.org/faq.html#synchronised-data so it would seem to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeap, I know. Also you can read my new comment!